# Update/Clear the datasource after changing the class library

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have already assigned a `datasource` to my `combobox` in my application and now I have added a property in the class library and have added the reference in this application.

Now I have to change the property in that `datasource` which is currently added in the class library.

When I tried to change the property I found the property is not yet updated in the `datasource`. So i'm unable to select that new property.

If I try to add a new `datasource` it is added and is that mandatory to change the new one to all the `combobox` in that form?

Now I have to either update the datasource or clear the `datasource` and add a new one.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to clear the datasource from the combobox? 
You can do that by

```
    combobox.Datasource = null;
```

I hope that is what you mean.